# Time based dynamic column name using concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm assuming it's not possible but I'd love to see if anyone can prove me wrong. I want to get the output of a query that uses time functions and concat to generate the name of an output column. If this was generated in code it wouldn't be a problem but it's SQL output being sent to an analyst I'd like it to be as legible as possible for them.

```
SELECT 
    source_domain,
    sum(IF(created_at BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE AND now() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE,1,0)) concat(now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,'-', now() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE),
FROM data_set
GROUP BY 1
```

Where the result would look something like:

```
| source_domain | 2020-06-29 12:00:00 - 2020-06-29 12:15:00 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
| abc.com       | 37
```

Comment: Create stored procedure which uses dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing is [NAME_CONST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_name-const). But it won't work the way you describe because the argument must be a constant string, not an expression. And the docs say it is for internal use only by MySQL, you shouldn't use this function in application code.

You cannot do this in one query. You have to do one query to generate the string you will use as the column heading for the second query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,'-', NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

Fetch the result of that query, and then use it in your subsequent query:

```
SELECT 
    source_domain,
    sum(...yadda yadda...) AS `<alias>`
FROM data_set
GROUP BY 1
```

You would interpolate the time range string where I have put `<alias>` above. Like all identifiers, it must be part of the SQL query string *before* you prepare the query.